# Function template return type

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new in C++. I'm working on a school assignment that requires to use a function template to find the maximum value of an array. The code seemed to work fine with normal functions until I changed it to a function template. I now receive an error:

```
maxcpp.cpp:9:16: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
        return *myArr[first];
```

Not quite sure what happened there but any help would be appreciated.

Here is the source code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T maxArray(T myArr, int first, int last){

    if(first == last){
        return myArr[first];
    }
    else 
    {
        int mid = first + (last-first)/2; 
        return(std::max(maxArray(myArr,first,mid),maxArray(myArr,mid+1,last)));
    }
}

int main(){

    int array1[] = {5,20,3,1};

    std::cout << maxArray(array1,0,4) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the type of `myArr`. Should it be `T`?

Comment: You told your computer that the first parameter to the template function must be the same as its return value. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Write `T* myArr` in the function declaration. Also the function call is wrong it should be `maxArray(array1,0,3)`

Comment: change the return type to "int", it will work

Comment: Thank you guys. So basically adding * before myArr in function declaration made it work. It does make sense now @ALX23z and I just noticed that in function call as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the argument type along these lines:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T maxArray(const std::vector<T>& myArr, int first, int last){

    if(first == last)
    {
        return myArr[first];
    }
    else 
    {
        int mid = first + (last-first)/2; 
        return(std::max(maxArray(myArr,first,mid),maxArray(myArr,mid+1,last)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess using a recursive algorithm is also part of your assignment?
Otherwise you can simply write (fixes in the comments are already applied):

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>

template <typename T>
T maxArray(T* myArr, int first, int last){
    return *(std::max_element(myArr+first,myArr+last+1));
}

int main(){

    int array1[] = {5,20,3,1};
    std::cout << maxArray(array1,0,3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's a [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/ETonhs).

Answer (score 0):

This is a due to the template argument deduction rules.

Given the following lines of code

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto x = func(arr);
```

The deduced types (of the argument and the return value) depend on how the function is declared.

OP's definition is similar to this

```
template <typename T> T func(T arg) {
    return *arg;  // <-- Error
};
```

Where `T` is deduced as an `int *` (the arrray decays to a pointer when passed to the function) and so is the type of `arg`. This leads to an error, beeing `*arg` an `int`, while the declared return type of this function should be an `int *`.

An option, as already noted, could be to change the signature into something like this

```
template <typename T> T func(T* arg) {
    return *arg;  //         ^^
};
```

Where `T` is deduced as `int`, while `arg` has type `int *`.

Another option, would be the following:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N> T func(T (&arg)[N]);
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Where the function accepts a reference to an array (in my example `arg` is deduced as a reference to an `int[5]`, the array doesn't decay to an `int *` inside the function). Note that the size of the original array is also accessible by the function as the non-type template parameter `N`.

As a proof of concept, this could be an alternative implementation of OP's program:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T max_in_array_impl(T const* first, T const* last)
{ //                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            
    if ( first + 1 == last) {
        return *first;
    }
    else 
    {
        T const* mid = first + (last - first) / 2; 
        return std::max(max_in_array_impl(first, mid),
                        max_in_array_impl(mid, last));
    }
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T max_in_array(T const(&arr)[N])
{ //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  arr is a reference of an array of N const elements of type N
    return max_in_array_impl(arr, arr + N);
    //                       ^^^  here decays to a pointer
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = {1, -35, 20, 24, 13};

    std::cout << max_in_array(array) << '\n';
}
```

Testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JE1n7HlI8G0gWGDs).